# Why environment variable set by SetEnv in apache httpd.conf cannot be passed to php?

Tags: apache-2.2, php, environment-variables, setenv, phpinfo

I set an environment variable in httpd.conf:

```
SetEnv http_proxy "http://localhost:3128"
```

But I cannot get this variable in php using `getenv`:

```
<?php
echo getenv("http_proxy");
phpinfo();
print_r($_ENV);
```

`getenv` returns empty and `print_r($_ENV)` shows the following content:

```
Array ( [LANG] => C [PATH] => /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin [NOTIFY_SOCKET] => /run/systemd/notify )
```

Interestingly, the environment variable is shown under the "Apache Environment" section of the `phpinfo` output.

(my system is apache 2.4/php 5.6/CentOS7)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP [5.6 has bee **unsupported**](https://www.php.net/eol) **for 3 years** now. Upgrade to a [current version](https://www.php.net/supported-versions) now! Then, change the following:

Use `SetEnv HTTP_PROXY "http://localhost:3128"` - environment variables are case sensitive.

Use `getenv(varname: "HTTP_PROXY", local_only: true)` to request a variable from the server environment.

If you do not explicitly specify to only receive local variables, you would instead get results from fastcgi, so for a varname starting with `HTTP_` that could instead [dangerously confuse unsafe code](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=72573) with headers and is [silently discarded](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/e7e2056d1a993a01c9d57fb2261066855d282d8f/main/SAPI.c#L1021). Opting out of the SAPI behaviour is [documented in the getenv() function description](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php):

> If PHP is running in a SAPI such as Fast CGI, this function will
> always return the value of an environment variable set by the SAPI,
> even if putenv() has been used to set a local environment variable of
> the same name. Use the local_only parameter to return the value of
> locally-set environment variables.

Comment: In php 7.4, getenv("HTTP_PROXY", true) still returns nothing. phpinfo() shows mod_php7 in Loaded Modules, which means I'm not using php as CGI?